# Laravel - Resource count month dates

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, model, resources

i use Laravel eloquent model to get data from db. Take all users with history logged from last 6 month.

DB result:

```
 {
            "id": 2,
            "permissions": 3,
            "is_banned": 0,
            "datetime_last_logged": "2020-04-20 09:59:25",
            "last_login_ip": "127.0.0.1",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "logged": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "datetime_logged": "2020-04-20T07:59:22.000000Z",
                    "datetime_loggout": null,
                    "login_ip": "127.0.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "datetime_logged": "2020-04-18T07:59:22.000000Z",
                    "datetime_loggout": null,
                    "login_ip": "127.0.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "datetime_logged": "2020-01-20T08:59:23.000000Z",
                    "datetime_loggout": null,
                    "login_ip": "127.0.0.1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "datetime_logged": "2020-03-20T08:59:25.000000Z",
                    "datetime_loggout": null,
                    "login_ip": "127.0.0.1"
                }
            ]
```

I need get count value from my logged field for example:
`October - 0, December - 0,  January - 1, February - 0,  March -1, April - 2`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the collection, you can use Laravels native Collection class to group the items by their respective months and then map over the grouped array to count the values:

```
collect($dbResult['logged'])
    ->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['datetime_logged'])->month;
    })
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return collect($item)->count();
    });
```

This returns a collection like this with the number of the month (starting at 1) as the key and the amount of occurences in the grouped collection as the value:

[image: example result]

If you fancy you can change the result of the groupBy operation to

```
return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['datetime_logged'])->format('F');
```

so it returns the name of the month instead of its number.

[image: example result]

---

My awful solution for your requirement to have all the months since six months filled:

```
$monthsInterval = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create(today()->subMonths(5), '1 month', today());

$placeholder = collect($monthsInterval)->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$item->format('F') => 0];
});

$userLogInsPerMonth = collect($dbResult['logged'])
    ->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['datetime_logged'])->format('F');
    })
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return collect($item)->count();
    });

dd($placeholder->merge($userLogInsPerMonth));
```

This monstrosity returns something like this:

[image: merged months example]

Comment: Its working.  But  i get ``Carbon::now()->subMonths(6);`` ? How can i write 0 when in any month user dont logged..?

Comment: A solution to that would be to create an additional "placeholder" array with the required six months span filled in (like `['January' => 0, 'February' => 0, ...]`) and merge the array with the actual values with the placeholder array.

Comment: I've added a solution for your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to work a lot with this data, I recommend that you create a new column in your table so that you can filter more easily.

You can get month whit Carbon :

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2020-03-20T08:59:25.000000Z')->format('F');
```

Output:

```
March
```

Also, you can make foreach:

```
$logs= [];
foreach($users as $user){
  $date = $user->datetime_logged;
  $month = Carbon::parse($date)->format('F');
  $logs [] = $month;
}
```

Here you have array with all months, you need only count for all months:

```
$count = array_count_values($logs);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [January] => 2
  [February] => 2
)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Hmm, its good but how can i get name 6 month before in Carbon? Because i need write 0 when in month user dont logged..?

Comment: this method does not return every month, only returns in which the user has been logged, you need to create an array with all the months, initialized every month to 0 and pass the values that the method returns in the months that the value is different, a solution that comes to mind